# Hibernate disable alter table to add foreign key and disable alter table to add constraint

Tags: java, database, hibernate

This is my first time using hibernate and whenever I run the project hibernate does this:

```
 Hibernate: alter table Enseigner add column matiere_reference varchar(255) not null
 Hibernate: alter table Enseigner add column professeur_code integer not null
 Hibernate: alter table Enseigner add constraint FKbuufx1q63fjcj0h9aaix4cbu3 foreign key (matiere_reference) references matiere (reference)
 Hibernate: alter table Enseigner add constraint FKk5idavh0u5pwc1n41h11y7tn3 foreign key (professeur_code) references professeur (code)
 Hibernate: select professeur0_.code as code1_2_, professeur0_.login as login2_2_, professeur0_.nom as nom3_2_, professeur0_.pass as pass4_2_, professeur0_.prenom as prenom5_2_ from professeur professeur0_ order by professeur0_.code
```

*(fields in database match the fields type in java classes)*

this is the database
//manyToMany

[image]

`hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">****</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schoolDB?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">eschool</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <mapping resource="com/Entity/Professeur.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/Entity/Matiere.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="com/Entity/Enseigner.hbm.xml"/>
  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
  
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I'm looking for a solution to disable creating foreign keys automatically

how can I solve this issue please?
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Real-world DB Migrations

You shouldn't use `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update` in the first place. This is needed only to play with Hibernate. In real projects we use Liquibase or Flyway for DB migrations. And we set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `validate` or to `none`.

And in the DB migrations you can create or not create FKs as you please.

#### Naming FKs in JPA

Also you can give names to FKs in JPA so that it hbm2ddl creates them with the right names.

```
@ForeignKey(name = "fk_professor)
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "professeur_code")
private Professor professor;
```

Judging from the comments this is what you were actually looking for. But still the proper way is to use DB Migration tools.

Comment: I struggled in the beginning because hibernate drops the table and recreats it whenever I call a method to update something in the table I looked for a solution and found out that I have to set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update`       For the FK I have to respect the FK names given in project statement, so I created two, each one refers to a table, but hibernate recreate another two foreign keys

Comment: @Jasmine, I've updated the answer to highlight FK names as well.

Comment: Sir please I'm struggling at fetching data from database in the same project can you help me please, here's the question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70500779/how-to-fetch-data-from-database-using-hibernate-manytomany

Answer (score 0):

Thank you **@Stanilav Bashkyrtsev**
What I did is the following :

I set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none`
And changed the FK names to **matiere_reference** and **professeur_code** in database and code because for some reason I ignore hibernate didn't consider the FK I added in database and in the *@Embeddable* class `EnseignerId` that contains foreign keys, so it kept looking for `professeur_code` and `matiere_reference` then generate an error because it could find them.

But now it's all good