# How to fetch data from database using hibernate ManyToMany

Tags: database, hibernate, many-to-many, hql, java-ee-6

I'm using hibernate with manyToMany relation and I want to display data from database

Thank you in advance.

I get this errors:

[image]

`database :`

[image]

Here is the code :

`Class EnseignerId :`

```
 @Embeddable
 public class EnseignerId implements Serializable {

//id professeur
@Column(name="professeur_code")
private int code;

//id matiere
@Column(name="matiere_reference")
private String reference;

public EnseignerId() {
    super();
}
//getters and setters...
```

`Class Enseigner :`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Enseigner")
public class Enseigner {

@EmbeddedId
private EnseignerId id = new EnseignerId();

//id prof
@ManyToOne
@MapsId("code")
private Professeur professeur;

//id matiere
@ManyToOne
@MapsId("reference")
private Matiere matiere;

@Column(name="heures")
private int heures;

//constructor getters and setters...
```

`Class Professeur:`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="professeur")

public class Professeur {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="code")
private int code ;

@Column(name="nom")
private String nom;

@Column(name="prenom")
private String prenom;
... 

@OneToMany(
        mappedBy="professeur",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Enseigner> matieres;   //List<Association> Class; //I followed a tutorial
//constructor getters and setters...
   public List<Enseigner> getMatieres() {
    return matieres;
}
```

`Class Matiere :`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="matiere")
public class Matiere {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="reference")
private String reference;

@Column(name="description")
String description;

@Column(name="volume")
int volume;


@OneToMany(
        mappedBy= "matiere",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Enseigner> professeurs;
//constructor getters and setters...
```

`getProfesseur() method :`

```
public Professeur getProfesseur(int code) {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory =  getSessionFactory(); //static method
    Session session =  sessionFactory.openSession();
    Professeur professeur = null;
    
    try {
        session.getTransaction().begin();
        System.out.println("------------Calling getProfesseur()----------");
        professeur = session.get(Professeur.class, code);
        if(professeur != null) {
            System.out.println(professeur);
        }else {
            throw new DAOException( "CODE INVALIDE!" );
        }           
    }
    catch(Exception e ) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return professeur;
  }
```

Saving data and getting **professors** who don't have an **Matiere** work. but getting **Matiere** or **professeur** whose primary key exists in the join table **Enseigner** generate errors when I do something like :

```
Professeur prof =profDAO.getProfesseur(2); //*generates errors* //the professor with id=2 exists in database
System.out.println(prof);

List<Enseigner> enseigner =  prof.getMatieres();  //*generates errors*...
List<Matiere> matieres = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for(Enseigner ens : enseigner) {
        matieres.add(ens.getMatiere());
        System.out.println(ens);
    }
    /*for(Matiere mat : matieres) {
        System.out.println(mat);
    }*/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has nothing to do with Hibernate. Please inspect the stack trace carefully: your `Enseigner.toString()` calls `Professeur.toString()` which in turn calls `Enseigner.toString()` again and so on.

I notice this problem more and more these days when people blindly use Lombok with its `@Data` (which should almost never be used), `@ToString` and `@EqualsAndHashCode`.  These generate respective methods that include *all* fields!

You need to remove these annotations or set them up so that they use only the fields that you really need. Most of the time your `equals()` and `hashCode()` are not needed when you write web apps with ORM. Hibernate ensures you don't have 2 instances of the same entity.

On the other hand `toString()` can be useful, but we shouldn't include all fields in it - just the ones that are helpful in identifying the entity.

Comment: Thank you again sir you've been a great help, somehow I didn't thought about this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have cyclic reference. You need exclude field `professeurs` and `matieres` by `@JsonIgnoreProperties`

Comment: I added it but then I got `@JsonIgnoreProperties cannot be resolved to a type` so I added an import and got `The import com.fasterxml.jackson cannot be resolved`